# Android App Play sound when holding down a button

Tags: android, android-emulator

new android dev hopeful here. I've been attempting to implement an app that, upon holding down the "ok" button, it will play the default ringtone in a loop.

What I have so far

```
package com.tick.helloAndroid;

import net.technologichron.android.control.NumberPicker;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class main extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
    private int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private MediaPlayer mp;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         // Set up the window layout
         setContentView(R.layout.main);

         final Button zero = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ok);
         zero.setOnTouchListener(this);
         Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE); 
         mp.setDataSource(this, alert);

    }
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mp.setLooping(true);
            mp.start();

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            mp.pause();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

[From doing some searching on SO, this seems to work for some people,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253371/play-sound-while-button-is-pressed-android) however, the line

```
mp.setDataSource(this, alert);
```

seems to not work. By not work, I mean that it forces an "Unhandled Exception Error", which upon doing a try-catch statement,

```
  try {
        mp.setDataSource(this, alert);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Toast.makeText(this, "args", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Toast.makeText(this, "sec", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Toast.makeText(this, "illega", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Toast.makeText(this, "io", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }
```

compiles without any error but crashes when I try to run the app on the android emulator, it does not print any of the above catches' strings.

Any thoughts and ideas about what I have done incorrectly will be most appreciated.

edit:  could it be from the fact that the emu does not have a ringtone?

Comment: Whats the exception? Remember: try/catch is for runtime errors.

Comment: Unhandled exception error, when you do a series of catch statements for the multitudes of possible exceptions, the app compiles fine, 0 errors. But when running it, it just crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forgot to instantiate mp....hahahahha